# how to handle BAD_EXEC in a code

Tags: iphone, objective-c, debugging

I have the following call to a function

```
  [[LocationDictionary sharedLocationDictionary] getLocation:[NSDate date]]
```

I put this code snippet in my app delegate and everywhere else, it worked fine.. however when I put it inside the block of

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
```

It directly breaks down with the following error:

```
-[NSCFString objectForIntervalOf:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x5e0b910
2011-04-06 16:42:56.668 SmarTrek[57331:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSCFString objectForIntervalOf:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x5e0b910'
*** Call stack at first throw:
```

Even when I do:

```
[[LocationDictionary sharedLocationDictionary] getLocation:[NSDate date]];
```

and change:

```
 - (id) getLocation:(NSDate *) date
{
    return [locationDic objectForIntervalOf:date];
}

- (id)objectForIntervalOf:(id)object {
    return nil;
}
```

Using NSZombie I got:

```
*** -[IntervalDictionary objectForIntervalOf:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x5e23930
Current language:  auto; currently objective-c
2011-04-06 19:51:43.595 Project[62298:207] *** NSInvocation: warning: object 0x5e23930 of class '_NSZombie_IntervalDictionary' does not implement methodSignatureForSelector: -- trouble ahead
2011-04-06 19:51:43.595 Project[62298:207] *** NSInvocation: warning: object 0x5e23930 of class '_NSZombie_IntervalDictionary' does not implement doesNotRecognizeSelector: -- abort
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you've got some memory problems (most likely an object is getting deallocated too early).  NSZombieEnabled and the Clang analyzer may help.

Comment: You're making a big assumption that this is the only method call that can be causing the problem.  At the very least, use the debugger, break on the exception and figure out where it's breaking.  But seriously, NSZombieEnabled is designed for exactly this kind of thing.

Comment: you are right an object is deallocated too early, but which one is it?

Comment: That's how zombies work... if you try to message a zombie, you get an exception and you can figure out what object it is.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're sending the objectForIntervalOf message to an NSString. As NSString doesn't respond to that message, you're getting an exception.

We need to see the code that uses objectForIntervalOf.

Comment: but why is it that it works on the app delegate and not in the locationManager delegate

Comment: I don't know. All I know is that you're sending the objectForIntervalOf message to an NSString and that's causing an exception.